# CakePHP bookmarker tutorial, login redirects to home.ctp instead of desired page

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

**This question is directed at those who have completed the cakePHP bookmarker tutorial.**

Im working on the cakePHP bookmarker tutorial from the book, and I'm having some problems. I'm at the part where you have to restrict the bookmarks access to the users that created them, and I added the code that was instructed in the book to the AppController.php and BookmarksController.php.

After doing so, I am unable to login, and I am redirected to home.ctp when Im supposed to be redirected to the bookmarks page. I cant figure out whats the issue and I hope I can find the answer here.

**Here my AppController.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link      http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since     0.2.9
 * @license   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Initialization hook method.
     *
     * Use this method to add common initialization code like loading components.
     *
     * e.g. `$this->loadComponent('Security');`
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize' => 'Controller',

            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],

            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],


            'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
        ]);

        $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Before render callback.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Event\Event $event The beforeRender event.
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Heres my BookmarkersController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Bookmarks Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\BookmarksTable $Bookmarks
 */
class BookmarksController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Users']
        ];
        $bookmarks = $this->paginate($this->Bookmarks);

        $this->set(compact('bookmarks'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmarks']);
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Bookmark id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Users', 'Tags']
        ]);

        $this->set('bookmark', $bookmark);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmark']);
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->patchEntity($bookmark, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Bookmarks->save($bookmark)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The bookmark has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The bookmark could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $users = $this->Bookmarks->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $tags = $this->Bookmarks->Tags->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('bookmark', 'users', 'tags'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmark']);
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Bookmark id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Tags']
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->patchEntity($bookmark, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Bookmarks->save($bookmark)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The bookmark has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The bookmark could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $users = $this->Bookmarks->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $tags = $this->Bookmarks->Tags->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('bookmark', 'users', 'tags'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmark']);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Bookmark id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->get($id);
        if ($this->Bookmarks->delete($bookmark)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The bookmark has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The bookmark could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        $tags = $this->request->params['pass'];
        $bookmarks = $this->Bookmarks->find('tagged', [
            'tags' => $tags
        ]);

        $this->set([
            'bookmarks' => $bookmarks,
            'tags' => $tags
        ]);
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        $action = $this->request->params['action'];

        if (in_array($action, ['index', 'add', 'tags'])) {
            return true;
        }

        if (empty($this->request->params['pass'][0])) {
            return false;
        }

        $id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->get($id);
        if ($bookmark->user_id == $user['id']) {
            return true;
        } 

        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }
}
```

**And finally, here's my UsersController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

        $this->set(compact('users'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Bookmarks']
        ]);

        $this->set('user', $user);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect');
        }
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->Auth->allow(['logout', 'add']);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->Flash->success('You are now logged out');
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

According to the tutorial, once logged in, I should be redirected to the bookmarks page.

Here're the links to the tutorial:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/part-two.html

Also, I'm still trying to figure this out on my own. Ill provide the solution if I'm able to solve it.

Comment: Did you try to add the parameter **loginRedirect** to your auth options, in AppController.php? 

Like this: 

     'loginRedirect' => [
                  'controller' => 'DefaultUserLoggedController',
                  'action' => 'welcomeAction'
              ],

Comment: @Bruno Lamps, no I haven't. However, I wasn't instructed to do so by the tutorial. I was just following the procedure. It says that I should be able to login properly, that is redirect to the proper page once the user logs in, and that isn't the case in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like the reason for this is that once the user logs in, the user is taken to the users page instead of the bookmarks page. Because restrictions were set, a user is not allowed to access the users page, obviously because the users shouldn't be allowed to access information about other users, including their hashed passwords and everything.

The restrictions are designed to send the user back to the previous page if the user makes a request that ends up denied. However, since the user is already logged in and hasn't logged out yet, it wouldn't make sense to send him back to the login page. So, the program sends the user back to home.ctp, aka the home page, without logging out.

The user can still access pages that are not restricted to him but the user is prohibited from making changes to anything that doesn't belong to him.